# Recursive partial in Ractivejs exceeding call stack

Tags: javascript, performance, ractivejs

Since discovering Ractivejs I am slowly moving my application over to it.

Before I built a html tree structure using vanilla JavaScript to create the elements, then appending it to the page after it was finished. I have recently moved it over to Ractivejs which works really well with a small tree structure but if it comes to a deeply nested object it exceeds the call stack.

Is there a way that I can append the elements I've built up in the JavaScript to the Ractivejs template and keep the Ractivejs events on it or is there a way of looping over the large object recursively without exceeding the call stack?

Examples

#### How the tree is built up in JavaScript

```js
var tree = {
  'childPages' : [{    
    'name': 'first child',
    'childPages': []
  }, {
    'name': 'second child',
    'childPages': [{
       'name': 'second first sub child',
       'childPages': []
     }]
  }, {
    'name': 'third child',
    'childPages': [{
        'name': 'third first sub child',
        'childPages': [{
            'name': 'sub sub child',
            'childPages': []
         }]
     }]
  }]
};


function buildTree (tree) {
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');;
  for(var i =0; i < tree.childPages.length; i++){
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = tree.childPages[i].name;
    ul.appendChild(li);
    if (tree.childPages[i].childPages.length) {
       li.appendChild (buildTree(tree.childPages[i]));
    }
  }
  return ul;
}

document.body.appendChild(buildTree(tree));
```

#### How the tree would be built in Ractivejs template

```js
var ractive = new Ractive({
  el : 'body',
  template: '#treeNode',
  data: {
'childPages' : [{    
  'name': 'first child',
  'childPages': []
}, {
  'name': 'second child',
  'childPages': [{
    'name': 'second first sub child',
    'childPages': []
  }, {
    'name': 'second second sub child',
    'childPages': []
  }]
}, {
  'name': 'third child',
  'childPages': [{
    'name': 'third first sub child',
    'childPages': [{
      'name': 'sub sub child',
      'childPages': []
    }]
  }]
}]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js"></script>
<script id="treeNode" type="text/ractive">
  <ul>
    {{#each childPages}}
      <li>
         {{name}}
          {{#if childPages}}
           {{> treeNode}}
          {{/if}}
      </li>
     {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually when you exceed the call stack it's because of the way Ractive handles missing data properties - if you have `{{with foo}}{{bar}}{{/with}}` and `foo.bar` doesn't exist, the `{{bar}}` reference is unresolved, so it 'goes up the context stack', and looks for `bar` instead.

Most of the time this is really convenient, but in cases like this it can be problematic, because if an item in the tree doesn't have a `childPages` property, Ractive will go up the stack to the parent - which sends us down the infinite recursion rabbit hole.

There are two solutions:

- Make sure every node in the tree has a `childPages` property, even if it's an empty array, or...
- Use *restricted references*. If you use `this.childPages` instead of just `childPages` (or `./childPages` - it's equivalent, you might have an aesthetic preference for one over the other) then Ractive won't look outside the current context for a piece of data. Here's an example of that, with all the empty `childPages` arrays removed - without the `this.`, we exceed the call stack immediately, but because it's there we're totally safe.

```js
var ractive = new Ractive({
  el : 'body',
  template: '#treeNode',
  data: {
'childPages' : [{    
  'name': 'first child'
}, {
  'name': 'second child',
  'childPages': [{
    'name': 'second first sub child'
  }, {
    'name': 'second second sub child'
  }]
}, {
  'name': 'third child',
  'childPages': [{
    'name': 'third first sub child',
    'childPages': [{
      'name': 'sub sub child'
    }]
  }]
}]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js"></script>
<script id="treeNode" type="text/ractive">
  <ul>
    {{#each this.childPages}}
      <li>
         {{name}}
          {{#if this.childPages}}
           {{> treeNode}}
          {{/if}}
      </li>
     {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it now does everything lightning fast! Also found some circular references within the object... So all of these optimisations working together are great :thumbsup: